# Regex for a sentence syntax

Tags: regex

I am trying to separate a String into different parts that match a specif syntax.

The String I am using as example is `Username 5/5, Version: 1.0 This is a custom message Sep 25, 2018`.

Currently I have this Regex `(\w+) ([0-9]\/[0-9]), (\w+): ([0-9][.][0-9][.]?[0-9]?)` which gives me The username, the `5/5`, the word `version` and the version `1.0`.

First, how can I ignore the `(\w+)`? Since it'll always be version and I only need the number after.
Second question, is it possible to get the big message after the version, then get the date after it?

Output needed:
`Username`
`5/5`
`1.0`
`This is a custom message`
`Sep 25, 2018`

Comment: What regex tool/language are you using?  Just tagging with `regex` doesn't necessarily mean you will get an actionable answer.

Comment: You may "ignore" `\w+` by removing it from the pattern, or removing the capturing parentheses, or encapsulating the space and `\w+` with an optional non-capturing group. Which one do you mean? What exact output do you need? What have you tried?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited with the output I need. To get a sentence I tried something like `(\s+[^.!?]*[.!?])` but it wasn't showing anything, I am using regex101 to test.

Comment: Try [`^(\w+)\s+(\d+\/\d+),\s+\w+:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2})\s*(.*)\s(\w+ [0-9]{1,2},\s*\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/NLJqWX/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(\w+)\s+(\d+\/\d+),\s+\w+:\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2})\s*(.*?)\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s*\d{1,2},\s*\d{4})$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gvmcva/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (username): one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+\/\d+)` - Group 2 (`5/5`)
- `,\s+` - a comma and 1+ whitespaces
- `\w+:` - 1+ word chars followed with `:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,2})` - Group 3 (version number):

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+){1,2}` - 1 or 2 sequences of a `.` followed with 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 4 (message): any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([a-zA-Z]+\s*\d{1,2},\s*\d{4})` - Group 4 (date):

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 to 2 digits
  - `,\s*` - a comma and 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

Try `(.*)\s(\d\/\d),\s*Version:\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*(.+?)\s*(\w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4})`

Capture the groups 1,2,3,4,5 to get the output you needed.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/SrFJYm/4)

Comment: You forgot to remove the unwanted spaces between capturing groups \s

Comment: I used space instead of `\s`.It won't make a difference

Comment: There's still spaces around "username " and " this is a custom message "

Comment: we can trim that spaces while capturing. Anyway, edited

Comment: This is now giving the expected result. Upvoting